# docker: logrotate is failing with missing directories in pattern

Tags: docker, logrotate, alpine

I'm using logrotate in a docker container. I'm injecting a bind volume into the container where logs should be rotated.
The folder structure is more or less the same, this path `/srv/apps` is injected into the container:

```
/srv/apps/*/logs/*.log
```

The only difference is, that `logs` could be a folder or a symlink. The target for the symlink in this case is not known to the container because it is outside of `/srv/apps`.

logrotate is doing nothing:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/apps_logrotate
extension is now .log

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /srv/apps/*/logs/*.log  forced from command line (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
```

I'm working on alpine 3.9, this includes logrotate 3.15.0-r0.
What can I do here?

Comment: I tried logrotate 3.8 based on ubuntu 18.04 and this is working. How can I get I work with mentioned version?